# How do I create a smaller matrix out of a larger dataset?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Say I have a matrix

```
  1 2 ~ 80
a x x x x
b x x x x
~ x x x x
z x x x x
```

and I would like to make a smaller matrix out of a, b, and r/ 3, 5, 7, 8.
How would I go about restriction the matrix to just

```
  3 5 7 8
a x x x x
b x x x x
r x x x x
```

I am attempting to restrict a gene matrix in R

Comment: `mat[, c(3, 5, 7, 8)]` or ...

Comment: ... or `mat[c("a", "b", "r"), c("3", "5", "7", "8"]` perhaps?

Comment: I am getting an error about incorrect number of dimensions.

Comment: Describe better what exactly you need.